# Select value in a ComboBox loaded with Objects

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I select the item in the comboBox with key "02"?

```
public class GenericComboBox
{
    private string _key = string.Empty;
    private string _value = string.Empty;

    public string Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public GenericComboBox(string key, string value)
    {
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }
}

//Add data
IList<GenericComboBox> data = new List<GenericComboBox>();

data.Add(new GenericComboBox("01", "01 text"));
data.Add(new GenericComboBox("02", "02 text"));
data.Add(new GenericComboBox("03", "03 text"));

comboBox1.DataSource = data;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

//comboBox1.SelectItem With key equal "02"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net 2.0: (data needs to be a List not an IList for this one.)

```
    this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = data.Find(delegate(GenericComboBox gc) {return gc.Key == "02"; });
```

.Net 3.5:

```
    this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = data.First(gc => gc.Key == "02");
```

Comment: How can I do in case of not having access to variable data?. 
For example if I select the comboBox in a button click event

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedItem = ((List<GenericComboBox>)comboBox1.DataSource).Find(delegate(GenericComboBox gc) { return gc.Key == "02"; });

Answer (score 1):

Set the `SelectedValue` property. The `ComboBox` will select the item with that value set on it.

Answer (score 1):

Override `Equals` in your GenericComboBox class:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   return string.Compare(Key, obj.ToString(), true) == 0;
}
```

Then this code should work:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = "02";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Dictionary instead of an IList?  Then you can retrieve the value using the key.